# Javascript callbacks and "this"

Tags: javascript, callback

I have the following Javascript code, and I'm trying to get a callback to work as shown below.  I want to see an alert with "123" in it.

```
var A = function(arg){
    this.storedArg = arg;
    this.callback = function(){ alert(this.storedArg); }
}

var B = function() {
    this.doCallback = function(callback){ callback(); }
}       

var pubCallback = function(){ alert('Public callback') };

var a = new A(123);
var b = new B();

b.doCallback(pubCallback); // works as expected
b.doCallback(a.callback);  // want 123, get undefined
```

I understand what is happening but I'm not sure how to fix it.  How can I get a callback function that references my a object?  In my case, I can make changes to A but not B.

Comment: Have you tried just alert(arg) ?

Comment: @Jack, I don't think the end goal is showing an alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you want is to pass the context to the `doCallBack`.

E.g.

```
doCallBack = function (callback, callee) { 
    callback.apply(callee);
}
```

So then you would do:

```
b.doCallBack(a.callback, a);
```

If you cannot modify the B then you can use closure inside A:

```
var A = function (arg) {
    var self = this;
    this.storedArg = arg;
    this.callback = function () { alert(self.storedArg); }
}
```

Comment: This would require modifying the B class, right?  Unfortunately, I cannot do this.

Comment: @Watusimoto I have added a second version for when you cannot modify B

Answer (score 2):

You can create a variable that holds the wanted scope for `this` by putting it into variable `that`

```
var A = function(arg){
    this.storedArg = arg;
    var that = this; // Add this!
    this.callback = function(){ alert(that.storedArg); }
}
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/vdM5t/

Answer (score 1):

> I understand what is happening (during the 2nd callback, "this" is b and not a)

No, JS is no class-based language where something could happen. If `function(){ alert(this.storedArg);` is just called as `callback();` (like in `b.doCallback`), the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) points to the global object (`window`).

To get around that, you'd have to change `A` to

```
var A = function(arg){
    var that = this; // store reference to the current A object
    this.storedArg = arg;
    this.callback = function(){
        alert(that.storedArg); // and use that reference now instead of "this"
    };
}
```

If you don't expect the `storedArg` property to change, you could even make it more simple:

```
var A = function(arg){
    this.storedArg = arg;
    this.callback = function(){
        alert(arg); // just use the argument of the A function,
                    // which is still in the variable scope
    };
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct; I had done some logging that showed this == b, but my statement did not make it clear where I had observed that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the context you want the callback to execute in:

```
var B = function() {
    this.doCallback = function(callback, context) {
        callback.apply(context); 
    };
};

b.doCallback(a.callback, a); // 123
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a9N66/

Answer (score 1):

Because inside `A.callback` function, `this` does not refer to `A` but to `window` object.

```
var A = function(arg){
    this.storedArg = arg;
    this.callback = function(){ alert(this.storedArg); }
    -----------------------------------^-----------------
}
```

You can try this,

```
var A = function(arg){
    this.storedArg = arg;
    var that = this;
    this.callback = function(){ alert(that.storedArg); }
}

var B = function() {
    this.doCallback = function(callback){ callback(); }
}       

var pubCallback = function(){ alert('Public callback') };

var a = new A(123);
var b = new B();

b.doCallback(pubCallback); // works as expected
b.doCallback(a.callback);  // alerts 123
```

Comment: `this` does not refer to `A.callback` (which btw does not exist), and neither should it refer to `A`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
b.doCallback(a.callback);
```

that just calls a's `callback` function without telling it to use `a` for `this`; so the global object is used for `this`.

One solution is to wrap that callback up:

```
b.doCallback(function() { a.callback(); });
```

Other solutions include [binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the callback to `a`, using [jQuery.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) (which is just a fancy way of doing my first solution), or passing in `a` to `doCallback` and invoking `callback` on `a` using [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).